# What is the most reliable method for creating a simple divider in HTML email?

Tags: html-email

I tried using a table row with a single column which contains nothing more than empty anchor elements and has a background color. This works in some clients but I wouldn't say most. I've also tried setting the border-bottom of a column and row but this also has very mixed results. Another option is using images...

Is there any solid technique for doing this? I'm fairly new to email design.

Answer (score 5):

There are several methods, if you want a horizontal "rule" under a paragraph, full paragraph width you can either:

```
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border:none; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;">My text plus at least two break tags for padding <br /><br /></td>
```

Or

```
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="Verdana;">Some content text here with no break tag after it.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border:none; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

the second method may add two pixels into the layout depending on which email client and rendering method is used. But is far more reliable because you can set the height to figuratively add "padding" under your text. (Padding does not work the same unilaterally across all email clients).

For more complex "padded" options, I'd suggest adding the `border-bottom` to an enclosing `<td>` then nesting a table with extra "padding" columns *using the `font-size:1px; line-height:1px;"` plus `&nbsp;` for Outlook hack.

Comment: A slight edit I'd suggest to your first example is that `<br>` or `<br />` will collapse in Outlook when used as padding at the start or end of a table cell. You should use `&nbsp;<br>` at the start and `<br>&nbsp;` at the end instead to avoid this. Double breaks still work fine between bodies of text.

Answer (score 0):

Well if i would want a divider in Email i will simply use `</hr>` tag and have a horizontal rule.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, but I didn't think styling a horizontal rule would be very well supported...

Comment: Ok, try and let me know! If you want to style the border then using css border is the best option i think.

Comment: <hr> is not what it used to be, since HTML5 arrived : http://html5doctor.com/small-hr-element/

Answer (score 0):

A table cell with a 1px border of your desired color is the most reliable way I have found it to render.

```
<table width="100%" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;">
Content Here
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Related, I have found that borders do not work on images in all email clients.

Comment: I tried this too but the border goes all the way around in some versions of Outlook :(

Comment: What versions? I have not had issue in '03, '07 or '10.

Comment: It was in 2010 and 2013, but not 2011. 2013 renders absolutely horribly especially when compared to 2010. This is based on Litmus tests and a screenshot from the client, which were identical.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your divider line is only a few pixels thick, I usually use an image say 10px x 40px, with the divider line vertically centered (although technically 1px x 40px would work). I'd then stretch the image to the full width of the table cell.

The reason it is so tall is that I also use the image for padding. The extra 'unnecessary' pixels aren't too much of an issue because the image is <10px wide.

The advantage is that this technique allows you to precisely control the vertical padding before and after, and also avoids the min cell height issue in Outlook which I think is 19px high...